# How Would i go about editing a span when theres two?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to edit a spans contents but the class the span is using is being used in another span

-the one i don't want to edit-

```
<span id="chat-subrooms-toggle" class="chat-column-title"> Chat </span>
```

but heres the one i want to edit

`<span class="chat-column-title"> Related Videos </span>`

I would prefer using

```
document.getElementByClassName("chat-column-title")[0] .innerHTML = "change here";
```

but with a method of eliminating the certain id

Comment: edit in what way? And why are there leading spaces in the attributes>?

Comment: If the element also has an `id` - you might be better off using it. Or rather matching the elements with a certain class that do not have an `id` attribute.

Comment: because when i use the class name it affects the first one which i don't want to do all i want to do is edit (related videos)

Answer (score 6):

Well, it happens the one you don't want to edit has an `id`, so you could use [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
var $span = $(".chat-column-title").not("#chat-subrooms-toggle");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/tugap/1)

There's also [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
var $span = $(".chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/tugap/2)

Then use the `$span` jQuery object to update the span in whatever way you mean by "edit."

---

Side note: I'm assuming in the above that you remove (or don't have) the extraneous spaces in your attribute values and tags; if you really have those spaces, the markup doesn't create spans at all (because of the space after `<`), and if you removed those but not the other extra spaces, the `id` value wouldn't match. E.g., I'm assuming the markup for the first span is this:

```
<span id="chat-subrooms-toggle" class="chat-column-title">Chat</span>
```

not what you have in your question.

Comment: lol nah i added the spaces to post it i couldn't figure out how to post the span without spaces + i tried this method it doesn't seem to work :( can't i use something like =======> document.getElementByClassName("chat-column-title")[0] .innerHTML = "change here"; and also is there a way to exclude the id?

Comment: @DarrenBrinx: The above works just fine, as you can see from the live examples.

Comment: @DarrenBrinx: To post markup in your question, type it normally, select it, and click the `{}` button in the toolbar (or simply indent it four spaces, as the big orange box next to the "Ask a question" text field tells you).

Comment: i tried your method but it doesn't seem to change anything in the code i'm overwriting tho, can i use `var $span = $(".chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").innerHTML("Related videos new text");`

Comment: @DarrenBrinx: *Look* at the live example. You don't use `innerHTML` on jQuery objects. You use jQuery's `html` function. (Or you use `[0]` to get the raw DOM element and use `innerHTML` on that.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('.chat-column-title').not('#chat-subrooms-toggle')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

`$(".chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle").html("Related videos new text")`

Comment: It's because of spaces in your attributes. Check out the top voted answer. I'm writing through a tablet, so it's hard to make you a demo.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would decorate the span with a data attribute and then edit based on that.

```
<span id="chat-subrooms-toggle" class="chat-column-title" data-column-type="chat">chat</span>
<span class="chat-column-title" data-column-type="related-videos"> Related Videos </span>
```

Then you can simply call:

```
var spanToEdit$ = $('span[data-column-type="related-videos"]');
```

to get the right span.